# Iterate through a string that has a comma separator in Crystal 2011

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a database that contains a field with comma delimited data, e.g.

```
  123,234,345,456,567,678
```

I am trying to get Crystal Report to display the data in a list e.g.

```
123
234
345
456 
567
678
```

As I am new to crystal what way would i write the code? do I use a for statement?

cheers

Rachael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// {@list}
Join( Split({table.serialized_field},","), Chr(10)+Chr(13) )
```

Add this field to the canvas.  Ensure that the field's 'Can grow' setting is enabled.